# Elastic Stack Azure deployment fails when running the custom script

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to deploy ELK on Azure with SSL/TLS and SAML configured as described in [this doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-deploy/current/azure-arm-template.html) by Elastic:

I am using the [following template](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace).

Everything works fine only if I do not configure the `http_cert` parameter.

The error I am hitting happens [at this line of the elastic install script:](https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace/blob/master/src/scripts/elasticsearch-install.sh#L533)

and it looks as follows:

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
      "message": "
VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'script'. Error message: 
\"Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=10
[stdout]
[04052021-20:51:32] [wait_for_started] seeing if node is up after sleeping 5 seconds, retry 60/60
[04052021-20:51:33] [wait_for_started] never saw elasticsearch go up locally

 Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
[stderr]
  0     0    0     0    0     0 --:--:--  0:00:14 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:15 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:16 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:17 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:18 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:20 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:21 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:22 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:23 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:24 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:25 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:26 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:27 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:28 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:29 --:--:--     0
100   151  100   151    0     0      5      0  0:00:30  0:00:30 --:--:--    31
100   151  100   151    0     0      5      0  0:00:30  0:00:30 --:--:--    39
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
```

My deployment looks as follows:

```
#http_cert=$(base64 /mnt/c/.../cert.p12)
#kibana_cert=$(base64 /mnt/c/../kibana.crt)
#kibana_key=$(base64 /mnt/c/../kibana.key)

az deployment group create \
  --resource-group myresourcegroup \
  --template-uri $template_base_uri/$template_version/src/mainTemplate.json \
  --parameters _artifactsLocation=$template_base_uri/$template_version/src/ \
                esVersion=7.10.0 esClusterName=censored\
                adminUsername=censored adminPassword=censored \
                securityBootstrapPassword=censored \
                securityAdminPassword=censored \
                securityKibanaPassword=censored \
                securityLogstashPassword=censored \
                securityBeatsPassword=censored \
                securityApmPassword=censored \
                securityRemoteMonitoringPassword=censored \
                loadBalancerType=internal \
                #esHttpCertBlob="$http_cert" \
                #esHttpCertPassword="censored" \
                #samlMetadataUri="censored" \
                #samlServiceProviderUri="censored"  \
                kibana=Yes \
                #kibanaCertBlob="$kibana_cert" \
                #kibanaKeyBlob="$kibana_key" \
                kibanaKeyPassphrase="censored" \
                logstash=Yes \
                authenticationType=password  \
                adminPassword=censored \
                vNetNewOrExisting=new \
                vNetName=censored \
                vNetExistingResourceGroup=censored \
                vNetNewAddressPrefix=censored \
                vNetLoadBalancerIp=censored \
                vNetClusterSubnetName=censored \
                vNetNewClusterSubnetAddressPrefix=censored \
```

How could I resolve this? I tried many things but always got this same error, unfortunately.
The logs in the  VMs did not give away any useful information as to why it failed.

Comment: I had the same issue and resolved it by not passing the http certificate: so `esHttpCertBlob="" esHttpCertPassword="".  I haven't figure out why that was the problem. I created a self-signed certificate to test the service, so maybe that's the issue. I also created this issue to see if someone responds: https://github.com/elastic/azure-marketplace/issues/401

Comment: Thanks @jorgenv, this is not possible to do (my question), I followed up with Elastic. Issue with the script.